# Wuxt.js (Nuxt.js) getting out data from axios response

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I want to fetch out menu items from the Wordpress json response with Wuxt framework (Nuxt + Wordpress), but I can't access the `data` object outside the fetch (error message is that data is not defined) 
This is my code

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Logo from '~/components/Logo'

export default {

  components: {
    Logo
  },

  async fetch ({ params, error }) {
    try {
      let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3080/wp-json/wuxt/v1/menu')
      return data
    } catch (e) {
      error({ message: 'Not found', statusCode: 404 })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can the `data` object be accessed, for inserting into the template?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fetch than all your data should be commiting into store, and accessed from it. If you want to return data, use [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api) method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the code a bit, that it returns a data function with variable, so it looks like this.

```
export default {
  components: {
    Logo
  },
  data() {
    return { menus: [] }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3080/wp-json/wuxt/v1/menu')
    .then(response => {
      response.json().then(menus => {
        this.menus = menus;
      })
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: this way your data from api wont be server rendered in case you need it